# Data Streaming from iOS Device to Android

Tags: android, ios

We are using `NSNetService` using Bonjour to display content entered in the iOS device to another iOS device. I wanted to find out if there is a way to communicate between iOS and Android so that we can display content on the Android device as well?

Thanks,
Raj